# Movie where a mad doctor creating an Frankenstein-type monster gets bitten by his creation

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw this horror movie in the 80s when I was a kid. There was this scene where a doctor tries to revive a patient, kind of Frankenstein type, and puts his fingers inside the patient mouth only to get bitten. The doctor tries to get his fingers out and pulls with so much strength that the stitches of the Frankenstein/patient neck starts to come out and the doctor ends up pulling the head out.

Comment: Feels a bit like something that would show up in one of the *of the Living Dead* films as well.

Comment: Not "The Reanimator", from 1985?

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I’m afraid it’s neither of those. I’m starting to think that maybe it wasn’t an American movie. I